# Proof of a lemma regarding packing in 2D

Tags: geometry

Let $C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_n$ be a system of nonoverlapping convex discs arranged in a convex hexagon $H$. Then, there exists a system of nonoverlapping convex polygons $R_1, R_2, \ldots, R_n$ such that $C_i \subseteq R
_i$ for every $i$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} s_i \leq 6n$, where $s_i$ denotes the number of sides of $R_i$.

This lemma was used to prove that the optimal(maximum) packing fraction in 2D is $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{12}}$

But I couln't understand the proof,

PROOF:(given in the textbook)

Let us start "growing" the sets C, within H so that they remain
convex and their interiors remain disjoint. It is easy to see that in a position
when none of them can be increased, all the expanded sets,$R_{i}$ aand $C_{i} \subseteq R_{i}$, are convex
polygons. Note that they do not necessarily fill H. Assume, for the sake of
simplicity, that any two sets , $R_{i}$ and $R_j$ are either disjoint or share a common
boundary segment. (The general case can be treated similarly.) Construct a
planar graph with $n + 1$ vertices which correspond to $R_{1},...,R_n$ and $H^{c}$ (the
complement of H), two vertices being joined by an edge if and only if the
corresponding faces touch each other. If e denotes the number of edges in this
graph, then

$3(n+1)-6 \geq e \geq \frac{1}{2}((\sum_{i=1}^{n}  s_{i}) + q -6)$

where where q denotes the number of points on the boundary of H that belong to more
than one $R_{i}$.
.
The proof proceeds by assuming the existence of $R_{i}$, but I wasn't able to show its existence or find any resource that proves this claim.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CalvinLin I am so sorry,  I have edited it

Comment: Can you state the name of the textbook, and the page number?

Comment: Combinatorial geometry. Janos pach pg 23

Comment: Are you uncomfortable with their implicit argument of "Consider all convex sets $R_i$, with disjoint interiors, that contain $C_i$. Order them by inclusion and pick the maximal element. Then $R_i ^*$ is a convex polygon"? Have you tried filling in the details?

Comment: Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Can you work through it and explain what you have concerns about? You can edit your post to show your work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150831/discussion-between-dynamite-and-calvin-lin).

Comment: @Calvin Lin What do you mean by the maximal element and why does it exist?